# how to retrieve friends open graph stories related only to my app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve on my friends wall only the content that will be posted on facebook via a custom open graph story that my Ios APP generates.

The end goal is to have a functionality similar to instagram where we can see what our friends posters and liked in a "FOLLOWING" tab.

Answer (score 0):

That´s not possible at all.

> All friends_* permissions have been removed.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: then if not possible will it be possible to get this (all the interaction a specific friend had from my app) for a particular friend? i would then iterate through my full list of friends

Comment: no, it´s not possible. all friend permissions have been removed. you can´t and shouldn´t get access to the wall of a friend for privacy reasons.